# Rewriteurl Category Id

Tags: .htaccess, categories

I want to remove my subcategory id's and redirect to new url with rewriteurl. I have lots of url like that

```
www.abc.com/category/(subcategoryid)-subcategory/(articleid)-article.html
```

Example;

```
www.abc.com/category/12-subcategoryA/1054-article.html
www.abc.com/category/23-subcategoryB/1072-another-article.html
```

vs.

to

```
www.abc.com/category/subcategoryA/1054-article.html
www.abc.com/category/subcategoryB/1072-another-article.html
```

Can you help me please.
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your  `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(category)/[0-9]+-([^/]+/[^.]+\.html)$ /$1/$2 [L,NC,R=302]
```